# How to disable automatically delete going in Register in vim

Tags: macos, vim

I recently setup VIM 8.1 with the option to cut content and put it in Mac clipboard. Now when I do visual mode selection and yank(y) it goes straight to the clipboard. And this feature is great for me, but I got issue now if I have something in my clipboard and I use x, d  commands to edit vim, it also goes to the clipboard, which makes more difficult to work.

Suppose I have copied something from the web and now I want to put in vim, but there is already 1-2 characters so I use x to delete them, now all content which I brought in the clipboard is replaced with these characters. Which make my work very complicated.

How can I disable this feature, so x, d command should not write on the Clipboard or Vim default register.

Comment: There isn't enough detail in this question for it to be answerable. You should [edit] it to show what you changed to "to put all visual yank(y) content into my mac clipboard". See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, `y`, `d`, `p`, etc. belong together. To be able use Vim effectively, they should all use the same default register/clipboard. Instead, use `"+y` or `"*y` to explicitly copy to a system clipboard.

If you want a handy shortcut, you can define a new keybinding for that, e.g. `nnoremap \y "+y`.

Comment: what about x? how can I change its default register?